# Show Average Price, High Price, and Total Price Fields In Alias

Tags: sql, group-by

```
SELECT tb_publisher.book_name, AVG(tb_book.price) as average, MAX(tb_book.price), SUM(tb_book.price) 
FROM tb_book 
INNER JOIN tb_publisher 
on tb_book.id_publisher = tb_publisher.id_publisher 
WHERE 'average' < 70000 
GROUP BY tb_publisher.publisher_name
```

I wanted to show a data where Average field is smaller than 70000 (supposed to be only 1 record that below that number), I can't comprehend why it doesn't want to show, instead of showing all the data. I tried all thing I know, so a help would be appreciate. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate DB you are using. I don't think you can use aggregate results in a `where`. I believe the `where` is evaluated first so your `'average'` is being looked at as a string.

Comment: Yeah, I think I should not do that, but if I didn't put the ' ', the sql goes error instead of showing the data, so I just post the script that way, lol. Anyway, thank you for the help, I appreciate it. ^u^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your query, you're doing:
`WHERE 'average' < 70000`, this means that you're comparing the `string 'average'` to the `integer 700000`, which of course is not what you want to do.

You're trying to filter on an aggregated column. That is the exact definition of the [`HAVING clause`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

```
SELECT tb_publisher.book_name, AVG(tb_book.price) as average, MAX(tb_book.price), SUM(tb_book.price) 
FROM tb_book 
INNER JOIN tb_publisher 
    ON tb_book.id_publisher = tb_publisher.id_publisher 
GROUP BY tb_publisher.publisher_name
HAVING AVG(tb_book.price) < 70000
```

In other notes, you might want to `GROUP BY` the primary key instead of the name.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the help ^_^, I never learned that in the college, it is suck that I didn't try the best at searching it. Sorry for the trouble, and thank you for the help.

Comment: @Ervan Don't forget to actually mark an answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases let you refer to the table alias in the `having` clause, so it would look like:

```
SELECT p.publisher_name, AVG(b.price) as average, MAX(b.price), SUM(b.price) 
FROM tb_book b INNER JOIN
     tb_publisher p 
     ON b.id_publisher = p.id_publisher 
GROUP BY p.publisher_name
HAVING average < 70000 ;
```

Notes:

- The unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should match the columns in the `GROUP BY`.  I'm not sure if you want the information by book or publisher, but I'm guessing by publisher.
- Use of table aliases.  These make queries easier to write and to read.
- Some databases do integer arithmetic.  If `price` is an integer and you want decimal places, you might need `AVG(b.price * 1.0)` or something similar.
- Not all databases support the use of table aliases in the `HAVING` clause.
- If you wanted to be really careful, you would aggregate by `p.id_publisher` because it is possible that two different publishers have the same name.

Comment: Wow, it's cool. Sorry, it wasn't the real table I post it here, it just a sample, make it easier for the readers to understand the question I wanted to ask. And also thank you so much for the answer, your script is easier to remember. And sorry for the trouble, God bless. ^_^